# Getting error in <feature> tag while using blackberry webworks 2.3.1.5,apache-ant 1.8.4,eclipse helios and blackberry simulator 9790

Tags: javascript, blackberry-webworks

I am using blackberry webworks SDK 2.3.1.5 and apache-ant 1.8.4 for running my blackberry simulator 9790.I am getting cordova error in  tag..cordova doesn't get supported.can any one suggest the answer?

The following error was thrown:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\hakuna>d:    
D:\>cd bbws    
D:\bbws>cd RSGT

D:\bbws\RSGT>ant blackberry run-simulator
Buildfile: D:\bbws\RSGT\build.xml

blackberry:

BUILD FAILED
Target "run-simulator" does not exist in the project "Build and Deploy a Cordova
BlackBerry WebWorks Project".

Total time: 1 second

D:\bbws\RSGT>ant blackberry load-simulator
Buildfile: D:\bbws\RSGT\build.xml

blackberry:

load-simulator:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: RSGT.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\bbws\RSGT\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\bbws\RSGT\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 68 files to D:\bbws\RSGT\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: D:\bbws\RSGT\build\RSGT.zip

build:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [ERROR]                     Feature cannot be found in any extension
(cordova.geolocation)

load-simulator:
     [echo] Simulator directory=C:\BBWP\simpack\9790
     [echo] Simulator directory=C:\BBWP\simpack\9790
     [echo] Simulator executable=C:\BBWP\simpack\9790/9790.bat
     [echo] Closing all running simulators...
     [exec] No sessions currently running.
     [exec] Result: 1
     [echo] MDS directory=C:\BBWP\mds

BUILD FAILED
D:\bbws\RSGT\build.xml:33: The following error occurred while executing this lin
e:
D:\bbws\RSGT\blackberry.xml:123: D:\bbws\RSGT\build\StandardInstall does not exi
st.

Total time: 21 seconds
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It shows you what is missing.

Comment: ya its showing that standardInstall folder doesnot exist in build folder of my project and also error in feature tag.I dono how to rectify this..can u please suggest some answers..

Comment: [exec] [ERROR]                     Feature cannot be found in any extension.here is the error showing..i dono how to overcome this.